# How (in RESTFUL web services) in BO to obtain the timestamp of a schedule for which I get the details?

Tags: web-services, business-objects-sdk

Please find below the extract from documentation showing the syntax of XML returned by the Web Services call. What is missing for me, is the timestamp. I wonder if you guys encountered this and have any idea how to obtain this (timestamp) information about the schedule via RESTFUL web services ?

```
<schedule >  
<id>9439</id >  
<name >GC-now-schedule< /name >  
<format type="webi"/>  
<status>Completed< /status>  
</schedule>
```

On the image below you can see the Instance time to be available in BO Web app, but I cannot obtain this info via RESTFUL web services.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can't, at least not with the current version of the REST SDK (tested in SAP BI 4.1 SP4).

Trying to retrieve more information through the Webi REST SDK for the instance will result in the error:

```
{
    "error_code": "WSR 00400",
    "message": "The resource of type 'Document' with identifier '3819322' does not exist."
}
```

Doing the same through the BI Platform REST SDK will not reveal the information you're looking for.

So the only remaining option is to use the BI Platform Java (or .NET) SDK which allows you to query the repository and retrieve all of the object's properties.

As the current BI Platform REST SDK implementation lacks a lot of the functionality found in the Java equivalent, I've logged an request on SAP's Idea Place. You could alway vote for the idea; hopefully this will result in SAP providing a more complete implementation. You can find the post [here](https://ideas.sap.com//ct/ct_a_view_idea.bix?c=BB5523E4-062F-4420-B35F-0B1F0D4769A9&idea_id=3AAFB023-E802-4E07-935D-D653D2FBE01A).

### Update

The *What's new* documentation for BI 4.1 SP05 lists *Get schedules with full details* as one of the changes for the Web Intelligence REST SDK. So you might be able to retrieve the necessary info by upgrading to SP05.

The SDK guide for this specific version is available [here](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sbo41/en/sbo41sp5_bip_rest_ws_en.pdf) (unfortunately the link seems to be dead right now).